# Decode nao funciona

Tags: c#, .net

Estou usando o `htmlagilitypack`, onde é feita uma extração de url dentro de uma div, o problema é que não está trazendo corretamente a codificação.

Requisição do .net:

```
string requisita = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)).ReadToEnd();
```

Recebo um link assim: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/combina%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o

Precisava que retornasse: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/combinação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/combina%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Tentei `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link)` e `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(link)` mas retorna mesma coisa.

Comment: em vez de negativar, é só colocar um comentário. a pessoa acha que a gente posta aqui de brincadeira?! que mal gosto

Answer (score 0):

Está retornando assim devido ao encoding 1252 que está usando:

> 1252  Windows-1252    Western European (Windows)

Utilize o UTF-8:

```
string requisita = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), 
                    Encoding.GetEncoding(65001)).ReadToEnd();
```

[Verifique nesse link da microsoft a tabela de encondings.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8#coment%C3%A1rios)